# Logout IdentityServer4 from .NET Core logs me back in

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I am working to convert a .NET MVC 5 application to core.  I am using an IdentityServer4 for Authentication/Authorization and I cannot seem to get the logout working.

```
public async Task Logout()
{
    await HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync("Cookies");
    await HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync("oidc");
    return Redirect("/");
}
```

I am using this line to logout, but when I do I see it redirect me back to the login url (because you need to be authenticated for "/") and it logs me back in automatically.  I have tried to delete the cookies in the logout method and no dice.

There is nothing in the IdentityServer log outside of the user is logged back in, so I don't think it's a configuration issue (worked in MVC5).  Has anyone else had this issue?  I think it's a small configuration issue that I am missing or logging out incorrectly.

I have tried this (below) but it throws a 404 on the /connect/endsession url.  I think the token is too large for the url (2700+ characters).

```
public async Task Logout()
{
    return SignoutAsycn("Cookies", "oidc");
}
```

My only thought, when working in the MVC5 app I was debugging using the url localhost.xyz.com and the login server was login.xyz.com.  Now I am debugging using localhost:44300 and login.xyz.com.  The redirect url is setup to be https://localhost:44300.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

So I added fiddler to the mix to watch what is happening between the Core version and the .NET version and when I logout in the .NET version you can see that there are some calls to the IS4 service (though I cannot see details) and everything works.

In the Core version there are no calls to IS4.  I can see that the cookies have been removed on the redirect, but the oidc information seems to be intact.

The /.well-know/ information looks correct as well.

**EDIT**

Log when hitting logout

2017-07-24T13:42:38.4069514-04:00 0HL6INDDIPV32 [INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:44300/Account/Logout   (e5be5b71)

2017-07-24T13:42:38.4164473-04:00 0HL6INDDIPV32 [INF] HttpContext.User merged via AutomaticAuthentication from authenticationScheme: "Cookies". (bdba1d38)

2017-07-24T13:42:38.4264444-04:00 0HL6INDDIPV32 [INF] Executing action method "Framework.Controllers.AccountController.Logout (Framework)" with arguments (null) - ModelState is Valid (ba7f4ac2)

2017-07-24T13:42:40.3758113-04:00 0HL6INDDIPV32 [INF] AuthenticationScheme: "Cookies" was successfully authenticated. (1805f3b3)

2017-07-24T13:42:40.3878092-04:00 0HL6INDDIPV32 [INF] AuthenticationScheme: "oidc" signed out. (d3f50c8d)

2017-07-24T13:42:40.4048013-04:00 0HL6INDDIPV32 [INF] AuthenticationScheme: "Cookies" signed out. (d3f50c8d)

2017-07-24T13:42:40.4127980-04:00 0HL6INDDIPV32 [INF] Executing RedirectResult, redirecting to "/". (d98d540e)

2017-07-24T13:42:40.4167958-04:00 0HL6INDDIPV32 [INF] Executed action "Framework.Controllers.AccountController.Logout (Framework)" in 1993.1739ms (afa2e885)

2017-07-24T13:42:40.4508858-04:00 0HL6INDDIPV32 [INF] Request finished in 2047.3797ms 302  (15c52c40)

2017-07-24T13:42:40.4558821-04:00 0HL6INDDIPV33 [INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:44300/   (e5be5b71)

2017-07-24T13:42:40.4668910-04:00 0HL6INDDIPV33 [INF] Authorization failed for user: null. (a4ab1676)

2017-07-24T13:42:40.4738760-04:00 0HL6INDDIPV33 [INF] Authorization failed for the request at filter '"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter"'. (8b6446cb)

2017-07-24T13:42:40.4818757-04:00 0HL6INDDIPV33 [INF] Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ([]). (f3dca807)

2017-07-24T13:42:40.5168613-04:00 0HL6INDDIPV33 [INF] AuthenticationScheme: "oidc" was challenged. (d45f1f38)

**EDIT**

I updated the code to do a couple of things.  I removed the claims from the token and it will now call the endsession end point and then redirect me logged back in.  I updated the code to post to the endsession (below) and samething.  Now if I call the /Account/Logout end point on the Identity Server it still will not log me out.

The identity server logs states it received a request to the /endsession endpoint, and no errors.

Thoughts?

```
private void Signout()
{
    var id = httpContext.HttpContext.Authentication.GetTokenAsync("id_token").Result;
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://login.xyz.com:8981/");
    var actionName = string.Format("/connect/endsession");
    var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("id_token_hint", id));
    values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("post_logout_redirect_uri", "https://localhost:44300/"));
    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
    var response = httpClient.PostAsync(actionName, content);
    if (response.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var item = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var t = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like you are not being logged out from IdentityServer correctly, and .NET Core middleware re-authenticates you. After you sign out are there any IdentityServer auth cookies left?

Comment: Yeah, I think that is it.  For some reason, it's not calling the endsession end point behind the scenes.  I cleared out the logs and used the old solution and I can see a call to the endsession end point, but with .NET CORE It doesn't seem to call that end point.  Any thoughts as to why?

Comment: Hard to say. Can you share Debug Output of your .Net Core app when you click call Logout? And does endsession URL in `/.well-known/openid-configuration` look correct?

Comment: Yeah the urls are correct.  I added fiddler in the loop (see edit above) and there are NO calls to IS4, unlike the MVC app where there are calls to /endsession

Comment: And what do you see in .NET Core app logs / console screen if running as an exe?

Comment: see edit above.  Nothing really, it says it logs out of oidc and Cookies and doesn't really log out of IS4.

Answer (score 3):

> I have tried this (below) but it throws a 404 on the /connect/endsession url. I think the token is too large for the url (2700+ characters).

Certain browsers from north west America (IE) and certain deployments (e.g. IIS on Azure) limit URL length to 2K by default.

For Azure there's a config workaround - IE is just a fact of life.

Two options:

- make your identity token smaller (less claims)
- the end_session endpoint also support POST - you can post the parameters instead of doing a GET. IIRC the middleware does not support the OOB - so you would need to make your own network request.

Comment: I read that it didn't support POST, so I will try that in a day or two.  Could MVC5 compress the id_token smaller than Core?  I say that because it works on MVC5 just not Core with the same endpoint.

Comment: IS4 supports POST (IIRC) - IS3 didn't. There is no difference between MVC and MVC Core. So maybe there is a different problem.

Comment: @leastprivilege Glad to hear that, but I couldn't find any info in the docs. Is there any security considerations?

Answer (score 2):

Found it!

Multiple issues

A)  I found an issue in the BuildLoggedOutViewModelAsync function to get the PostLogoutRedirectUri correctly.  I apparently wasn't setting it back to itself.

```
PostLogoutRedirectUri = logout?.PostLogoutRedirectUri == null 
    ? logout?.Parameters["post_logout_redirect_uri"] 
    : logout?.PostLogoutRedirectUri,
```

B)  The clients in Identity Server need the PostLogoutRedirectUris to have the ~/signout-callback-oidc and in the .net core client itself you can set it to what ever.

Then use return new SignOutResult(new[] { "oidc", "Cookies" }); to logout and redirect back in.

Hopefully all of this mess will help someone else out!